# UICollectionView horizontal continuous loop

Tags: uiscrollview, ios6, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have a UICollectionView with custom UIViews for each cell. The UIView takes up the whole screen and you can horizontally navigate to each of the 4 different UIView/cells. This all works fine and uses a pager to indicate which page of the collectionview you are on.

I have looked around google and the like to see if I could get it to loop back to the beginning after you navigate passed the last cell. So for example:

I start at the 3rd cell, navigate to the 4th, then when i swipe to the right, it will go back to the first cell (pager will reflect that you are on the first page) and continue on from there.

Is this easy to do? Or am I missing something?

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need 3 UIViews, to hold the image to the left of your current view, the image to the right of the current view, and the middle view, the one that is currently onscreen.

So lets say we have UIImages A B C D and UIViews 1 2 and 3

We are looking at View 2, image B. Page left will take us to image A, page right to image C.

As you swipe left/ page right, view 3 becomes the onscreen view with image C. When paging comes to rest, you swap the views contents around so the user is actually looking at the middle UIView2 again, with image C. View 1 has image B, view 3 has image D.

Scroll right again, and do the same shuffle. Now you have

```
View 1 -> image C
View 2 -> image D
View 3 -> image A
```

Next page right

```
View 1 -> image D
View 2 -> image A
View 3 -> image B
```

so on, ad infinitum in either direction

There is a nice WWDC video on this subject from 2011. Its worth digging out. [It's the UIScrollView demo video](http://bit.ly/wwdc2011ScrollView) ([Documentation as PDF](http://bit.ly/wwdc2011ScrollViewPdf)) You don't need Collection Views to do this, although there is no reason why you shouldn't...

Comment: I am afraid it is a bit more complicated than images within the view, these views are loaded from the storyboard (As opposed to using nibs and loading them in) and they each have their own view controllers and such that get inited. Also, the use of the uicollectionview, while not absolutely mandatory, is strongly recommended to keep consistent with the rest of the app. Do you think I could set the number of cells to some really high number, then move the contents and all of that to the next cell? (I think I saw that somewhere, but that must have performance issues no?)

Comment: Even if its more complex, the principle should be the same, you are shuffling your backing data around when your collection view is in a resting state. I have done this successfully on scrollviews, tableviews, and hierarchies of table views within table views without any issues. If you don't want to mess with your backing data you can pull it into a temp data store and mess with that instead? I've also done the high-number-of-cells thing, but that is just to keep up the illusion while we are live-scrolling through data. It's never going to be infallible.

Comment: Thanks for your help He Was, The theory here seems sound and should translate ok across to my collectionview. I am going to try and duplicate the first cell after the last and vice versa and and snap into the cells. Once done decelerating ill move the user to the "real" first cell or the "real" last cell depending on direction. Keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: @JakeTheBraek That sounds about right... but I assume you mean the first cell _data_ not the first _cell_, you should leave that to the CollectionView to handle.  Maybe you could update your question or something when you have a result that works - or start a new question if it doesn't(!) Your pager won't really make sense for an infinite list, you may have to rethink that.

Comment: I will answer the post below with my solution, so far it is coming along, the pager will make sense when you see it in context. The best way to describe it is I am creating a carousel.

Comment: Using a standard UIScrollView for the carousel may work better than a UICollectionView. UICollectionView has optimized memory management for an arbitrary number of cells, but a carousel only needs a single UIScrollView with 3 UIImageViews. The simpler solution is usually better.

Answer (score 3):

Alright ready for this hotness?

So in my main view controller's viewDidLoad I identify the views to load into the uicollectionview cells in an array:

```
NSArray *vcs = [@"view5", @"view1", @"view2", @"view3", @"view4", @"view5", @"view1"]
```

I also set our pagecontrol count to:

```
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = vcs.count - 2; // for the fake first and last cells
```

I then instantiate the viewcontrollers in the main view controller's viewDidLoad as well as set the alpha for the collectionview to 0. Then in our scrollViewDidEndDecelerating I handle the Carousel (go from last cell to first and first cell to last) and updating the pageControl to reflect the "real" page number.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Snaps into the cell    
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    float fractionalPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);

    self.pageControl.currentPage = page - 1; // because our first cell is the last cell for animation purposes only

    // Carousel from first to last and last to first while updating pagecontrol
    if (page == 0) {
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.activeGaugeClusters.count - 2 inSection:0]
                                    atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                                            animated:NO];
        // Set our pagecontrol circles to the appropriate page indicator        
        self.pageControl.currentPage = self.activeGaugeClusters.count - 2;

    } else if (page == self.activeGaugeClusters.count -1) {
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]
                                    atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                                            animated:NO];
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    }
}
```

Then in the collectionview implementation I do the following:

```
numberOfItemsInSection = vcs.count
```

and viewDidAppear for loading the first cell (whether it is the cell at indexPath.row == 1 or 2 or 3... (1 being the first real page not 0)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.lastGaugePanel inSection:0]
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                                        animated:NO];
    self.pageControl.currentPage = self.lastGaugePanel - 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.collectionView.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}
```

I think that about sums it up. The rest of the implementations for both the main vc and the collectionview are standard. So now I have a collection view that loads up other views and their VCs that each have their own animation or whatever. I save the indexPath.row to NSUserDefaults so that the cell that I was in when I leave is the first cell to show on the next load.

Hopes this helps someone, I know it did for me, unfortunately the use of 3rd party libraries was discouraged so I had to build this bad boy up (with help from @He Was, thanks again!)