# Using SwipeGester to swap views(of the same instance) - screenshot inside

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Here is a screenshot of a view that I have right on my device.

[image: Ipad Screenshot]

The design issue that I am having here is that the top part of the screen is always going to be static - as far as its placement. The rest of the screen are a row of buttons added to this view programmatically. The arrows represent the idea that you could swipe in 4 directions(from top, from bottom, from left and from right) which would animate a new view onto the screen. This view is the same instance as the view before it. In fact all these views are the same instance but the buttons will be different.( i dont want to get too specific here.)

My design right now calls for pre-loading the views ahead of time. The data for each button for each view will be in core data. I will not know ahead of time how many views there are. One view might just have a view to the right that you can swipe in from the right and that view might have a top and bottom arrow - that would allow you to swipe from bottom or top that would be another view(same UIView subclass). So basically a tree of views.

I guess I am trying to figure out my options. A NavigationController is not really what i want because i have no need for a navigation bar, although in my mind it makes sense that i would have an array of view controllers here each with its view property pointing to each view that is allocated and then as i swipe i would bring in the appropriate view by using the view controller index.(through some animation code)

Another possible option would be UIScrollView but that seems cumbersome and may not be what i would really want.

One of the easiest setups would be to create a XIB file that would consist the top part of the screen and on the bottom an empty UIView that i would programmatically populate with the buttons(and their unique data). The problem that I am havign with this is, is how would i swap the views this way. I guess i could make the rootViewcontroller the first viewcontroller instance with the first view and then swap them.

I guess I am wanting to see if anyone had any questions or suggestions to come up with the easiest(most modular) approach to swiping in different views. Is using an array of view controllers the way to go?

Comment: It seems as if you have a grid of data here. Have you thought about UICollectionView? With just a single screen-sized cell showing at a time?

Comment: well i have read about that - the gist of my question was trying to figure out how to swipe between views (that is a partial view) just the buttons not the top part of the screen. the best way to set that up. is setting up one XIB file enough? Just using an array of UIView subclasses is ok with me...

Comment: come to think of it maybe i need to be using a navigation controller. looks like you can hide the navigation bar and not even use it. then create a stack of view controllers(each one using its view property to point to a UIView instance) and then use the swipe gesture to animate in a view controller of my choosing.

Comment: It's one screenful of stuff so one XIB is enough.

Comment: Right so i would have a headerViewController - which contains the top part of the view then a buttonViewController lets call it that would actually be a navigation controller?? then i could stack on view controllers as i see fit and assign the first view controller view instance to be the rootViewController. what do you think? seems like this would work if you can have more than one view controller per XIB file

Answer (score 0):

One Xib is enough for you (for this part of your app anyway).

Don't use a UINavigation Controller. The NavController metaphor is one of a stack of cards. You don't have that data structure.

The general idea is one ViewController for one screenful of stuff. If you feel the need for two viewControllers (one for the top part, one for the bottom part) then you are going to have to look at custom container controllers, to ensure that the contained controllers receive their instance methods correctly (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, etc). An example container controller managing a pair of viewControllers is the iPad splitViewController. But I don't think you need to do this.

I suggest placing a scrollView on the lower half of the screen and using that to manage your data views. If the upper part of the screen also needs to change (under other conditions) you could even have two scrollViews, one up top, the other below. They can be paged, and contain views that are the exact size of the respective screen portion. They can share their single containing viewController as a common location for their delegate methods.

I can't really help you with more detail, as I don't have a precise enough idea what you want to achieve. Perhaps you should try and implement it one of these ways and come back here with more questions as your ideas become concrete. Start out with the simplest idea (eg scrollView inside a single viewController), only chuck it out when you find you have to break it!

**update**
following your comments, I do think a scrollView might work for you. I think that managing a stack of view controllers with a custom container controller (as Rob suggests) could get overcomplicated. You will have to create your own custom container controller, the pre-existing ones such as UINavigationController are *not* appropriate for your data strucure (from what I can gather anyway).

You won't need to manage tons of UIViews, in fact you only need 5 - one for the onscreen portion of the scrollView, one for the screen immediately left and right, and similarly for the immediate one above and below. You can reuse these views as you swipe, much the way that tableViews reuse their cells. The rest of it will be about manipulating your data so the right content is arranged in the views as they come onscreen.

See my answer to this question for some more ideas on this: [UICollectionView horizontal continuous loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249525/uicollectionview-horizontal-continuous-loop/14249823#14249823)

Comment: thanks for the help! the overall idea that i wanted to achieve was, is that i am going to have X number of UIView subclasses, each with a row of these buttons. I wanted to use the SwipeGesture to bring one of these views (animated) onto the screen depending on which direction the user swipes. The swipegesture part is easy - I was just wanting to find out the best way to store these views(an array of viewcontrollers?) to where when one swipes I could animate the appropriate view on the main screen. does that make more sense?

Comment: See my updated answer. You could store a stack of views, but better you could store a stack of the data needed to create the views, then create them (or reuse them) as you need.

Comment: responding to your update - it looks like UIScrollView might be the way to go but i wont have just 5 UIViews. For example, if i swipe in a view from the right that view might also have arrows(depending on the view data) whereby i could swipe up, right, down to another view(which would have a row of buttons(with diffrent data) and of course to the left to bring me back to the previous view. I also will need the ability to "jump" to a view not directly above, below, to the left or the right - so i wont always be using swipe to change to a different view.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. This screams custom container view controller to me (if iOS 5 and above). See [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) in the *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.*
2. You talked about using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. You could always contemplate `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, too. It's nice to have continuous gestures. Think about reading a book where the page swipe tracks your finger, but you can stop and go back, mid gesture. Sure, start with swipe gestures for now, but if your UX lends itself to it, you can always contemplate continuous gestures in the future.
3. You said that you're planning on "pre-loading the views ahead of time". Generally, given the limited memory capacity of mobile devices, you'd want to be more conservative than that. Maybe load the current view, and the four ones that you're likely to go to in each of the four directions (so that you can present them instantaneously), but leave it at that. Once you go to one of the four possible destinations, then go ahead and release the ones that are not reachable from the current one and tee up the ones that are.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the input. I tried to present want i wanted to achieve(hopefully better condensed) to He Was a minute ago. I definitely do not want the user to be able to go back mid gesture so thats why i went with the SwipeGester. This is also going to be iPad only and landscape mode only. I guess i would have to use Instruments to see how much memory i am consuming when i have a certain number of views(you recommended 4) versus more. I definitely do not want to be a memory hog. Any other comments from my comment to He was above? thanks again for the response!

Comment: Also i wanted to add that if i did go with a custom container would be still make sense to have an array of view controllers so that when the user swipes i can navigate to the appropriate view controller that i need and then animate that onto the screen? Under the link you posted the "A Navigation Controller Manages a Stack of Child View Controllers" seems to go with my idea of having a stack of view controllers...

Comment: @geeksweep No, I don't have any comments on your exchange with He. Like I said, I'd just use custom container. If the performance of the UI demanded it, I'd preload the four controllers I could swipe to. If it didn't need it, I wouldn't even do that. But I most certainly would not load an array of all of the controllers.