# Make UIScrollView Loop iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I apologize in advance for a basic question but I am new to iOS and Arrays but I would like to loop the UIScrollView that I made with the pictures in it once it gets to the end instead of stopping.  Do I reset a variable back to 0 once it knows my pagecount = 3? How would i go about this?  Thank you!

```
 int PageCount = 3;
    NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png", nil];
    UIScrollView *Scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    Scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
    Scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:Scroller];
    int width=Scroller.frame.size.width;
    int xPos=0;
    for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, Scroller.frame.size.width, Scroller.frame.size.height)];
        [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [Scroller addSubview:ImgView];
        Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
        width +=Scroller.frame.size.width;
        xPos  +=Scroller.frame.size.width;
    }
```

Comment: try this Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

Comment: Instead of something? Where would I put that? Thank you

Comment: Instead of this Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0); put Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

Comment: That wont allow it to scroll anymore unfortunately.  Anything else to add?  Thank you for your help

Comment: That's not such a basic question at all. Try searching through last year's WWDC videos, I know there is one that covers endless scrolling. You can access the videos via the developer portal, which means you must be a registered developer.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking at the "Street Scroller" trying to understand it

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, you want endless scrolling. So, may be you can try this. use an infinite loop, and use index = counter %3 , to get the correct index.

Comment: That sounds like a great thing to try! Can you help me possibly implement that idea?  I would be really appreciative!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249525/uicollectionview-horizontal-continuous-loop